# How to include multiple arguments to seasonal_decompose for ARIMA forecasting?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, arima

I would like to forecast multiple variables over quarters. Currently, my code can only work with one column. And I would also like the plot to display the each x-axis position as a date or quarter instead of arbitrary numbers.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
    from datetime import date, timedelta
    import datetime
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
    from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
    from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_pacf
    from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
    import statsmodels.api as sm
    import warnings
    
    from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode,  plot
    from plotly.graph_objs import *
    init_notebook_mode()
    
    'set filepath'
    
    inputfilepath = 'C:/Documents/' \
                'Forecast/Input/' \
                    'Forecast Data csv.csv'
                            
    df = pd.read_csv(inputfilepath)
    
    'Convert column from object to datetime'

df["Time Period"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time Period'], format="%d/%m/%Y")

print(df["Time Period"].dtype)

print(df)


'display graphical output using df columns and rows and dependant and independant variables'
    
    import plotly.express as px
    figure = px.line(df, x="Time Period", 
                      y=["HR","Legal","Fin","Leadership" \
                        ,"Market","UX","Overall"],
                     title='Quarterly scores')

result = seasonal_decompose(df["HR","Legal","Fin","Leadership" \
                        ,"Market","UX","Overall"],
                            model='multiplicative', period = 3)

fig = plt.figure()
fig = result.plot()
```

The line:

```
>result = seasonal_decompose(df["HR","Legal","Fin","Leadership" \
                            ,"Market","UX","Overall"],
                            model='multiplicative', period = 3)
```

gives me the following error:

> KeyError: ('HR', 'Legal', 'Fin', 'Leadership', 'Market', 'UX', 'EM&T')

and if, instead I use:

```
>result = seasonal_decompose(df["HR"],["Legal"],["Fin"],["Leadership"] \
                                     ,["Market"],["UX"],["Overall"],
                                    model='multiplicative', period = 3)
```

I get the following error:

```
>TypeError: seasonal_decompose() got multiple values for argument 'model'
```

The only way I've gotten it to somewhat work is to write an individual line for each variable:

```
result1 = seasonal_decompose(df["HR"],
                                      model='multiplicative', period = 3)

result2 = seasonal_decompose(df["Legal"],
                                      model='multiplicative', period = 3)

result3 = seasonal_decompose(df["Fin"],
                                      model='multiplicative', period = 3)

result4 = seasonal_decompose(df["Leadership"],
                                      model='multiplicative', period = 3)

result5 = seasonal_decompose(df["Market"],
                                      model='multiplicative', period = 3)

result6 = seasonal_decompose(df["UX"],
                                      model='multiplicative', period = 3)

result7 = seasonal_decompose(df["Overall"],
                                      model='multiplicative', period = 3)

fig1 = plt.figure()
fig1 = result1.plot()  

fig2 = plt.figure()
fig2 = result2.plot()  

fig3 = plt.figure()
fig3 = result3.plot()  

fig4 = plt.figure()
fig4 = result4.plot()  

fig5 = plt.figure()
fig5 = result5.plot()  

fig6 = plt.figure()
fig6 = result6.plot()  

fig7 = plt.figure()
fig7 = result7.plot()
```

Which gives me this example of HR where the x-axis doesn't really make sense to me:

[image]

Is there a way to incorporate all these variables into one 'result' variable and one plot graph?

Comment: I am confused by the usage of `matplotlib` and `plotly` in your code. it looks like you're creating both plotly figures and matplotlib figures – do you want a plotly or matplotlib based solution?

Comment: @DerekO for the place I am struggling with right now, I want a matplotlib solution. Plotly was only used for the first plot. If it helps, this is the resource I am basing my model on:
[link] (https://thecleverprogrammer.com/2022/09/05/business-forecasting-using-python/)

Comment: `result = seasonal_decompose(df["HR","Legal","Fin","Leadership","Market","UX","Overall"], model='multiplicative', period = 3)
fig = plt.figure()
fig = result.plot()`

Is the section I want to fix. So far I've found that my dataset may be a considered uniariate? I am unfamiliar with ARIMA as this is my first time using this model.